# How do I resize a window (animating)? Hiding and unhiding menus

Tags: cocoa, macos, search, animation, window-resize

Yeah, I did my homework and I found the `setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES` but I don't understand how am I find out the height necessary to make it bigger or smaller. Let me exemplify: I'm making kind of spotlight search tool but when the user start the app it will just have a textfield (to type in the search keywords) and a button (Filter Settings) and the window fits the size of these two objects (NOTE: The window start position is on the center and on the top of the screen). When the user hits the "Filter Settings" button I want the window to make an animation going down and then showing the "check box group" that filters the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you need to find out the height of the check box group that you are adding to the view. An easy way to do this is to make a seperate view in your nib that contains the check boxes. Hook up the view to the window using IB, and when it is time to display the check boxes add that view to the windows content view and animate the window resize.